# How can I implement a TextWatcher on an Activity

Tags: android, textwatcher

Implementing a `TextWatcher` on an Editable like `EditText` is quite simple. However, I want to listen for key input without a specific Editable in focus so that the user can launch the `activity`, without clicking on an `EditText` or anything. So you can just start typing (hard keyboard) or hold the menu soft key until the soft keyboard comes up and then I want to register these key events.

I have tried having my `Activity` implement `TextWatcher`, however the callbacks like `onTextChanged()` never get called. Has anyone ever done this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think at that point you want to switch to [Activity.onKeyDown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) and related.

Comment: Seems like its impossible to add a TextWatcher. I have switched it to just listen to the onKeyDown() event callback. Which works.

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
      if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A)
       //Do what I want with an A, etc.
      return true;
     }

Comment: Yes.  `TextWatcher` is specific to `View`s that have editable text.  An `Activity` is not a `View`.  `View`s that have editable text are already overriding `onKeyDown()` and `onKeyUp()` and all that, so they make changes available to you through `TextWatcher`.